# Advice on C/FORTRAN wrapper library

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fortran

I am trying to compile some source code and I am having issues. The code is written in C and FORTRAN and I am running into an issue with my compilers going from one to the other. This is the error message being returned;

```
mod_par.o: In function `__mod_par_MOD_domdec':
mod_par.f90:(.text+0x35a47): undefined reference to `partition_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [fvcom] Error 1
```

This is what I believe to be the offending bit of code from the file mod_par.F;

```
# if !defined (PARTITION_SPECIAL)
```

So I have been advised that this is a common problem encountered due to different naming conventions in C and FORTRAN. I have been give some advice on how to go about solving the problem, however, I don't understand the advice. It is as follows;

1) Work out which library hosts this partition function

2) Read through the docs for that library to find out how to generate a fortran wrapper library

3) Make sure you link through to the wrapper library as well as the original library

Anyone able to put this into laymans terms for me/advise on how to proceed/point me on to info to help me proceed? Let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: cheers, I wasn't sure whether to attach them or not

Comment: Which is calling which? Anyways, look up ISO_C_BINDING.

Comment: I actually resolved this the issue was that I was building the application using mpi compilers and the METIS library that was required for a parallel build was not linked. I linked this and the application is now built. I don't know if the moderators what to delete this post as this was a bit of a derp on my part.

Comment: *don't know if the moderators what to delete this post*  Maybe they will, maybe they won't.  But you can delete it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I actually resolved this the issue was that I was building the application using mpi compilers and the METIS library that was required for a parallel build was not linked. I linked this and the application is now built. – deiniol

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your answer? I have the exact same problem and I cannot fix it. In mod_par.F, I do not have a line like you mentioned:

`# if !defined (PARTITION_SPECIAL) `

I have a few lines similar to 

`!$ CALL PARTITION(NPROCS,NGL,MAXVAL(NVT),loc(NVT),loc(EL_PID))`  

Here is the error I get during compilation: 

`mod_par.o: In function mod_par_mp_domdec_': mod_par.f90:(.text+0x7af): undefined reference to partition_' makefile:125: recipe for target 'fvcom' failed`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is the last line during compilation:

`mpiifort  -O3   func_pointer.o mod_prec.o ....... swancom3.o swancom4.o swancom5.o   -L/home/onur/FVCOM3.1.6/FVCOM_source/libs/install/lib -lmpi   -lmetis -L../METIS_source -L/home/onur/FVCOM3.1.6/FVCOM_source/libs/install -lnetcdf -ljulian -Llibs/julian         -o fvcom
mod_par.o: In function `mod_par_mp_domdec_':
mod_par.f90:(.text+0x7af): undefined reference to `partition_'
makefile:125: recipe for target 'fvcom' failed
make: *** [fvcom] Error 1
`

Comment: @theenemy - You should direct your request \@deiniol.